# No glyph found after getting Text and Font from existing pdf

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

My goal is to transfer textual content from a PDF to a new PDF while preserving the formatting of the font. (e.g. Bold, Italic, underlined..).
I try to use the TextPosition List from the existing PDF and write a new PDF from it.

For this I get from the TextPosition List the Font and FontSize of the current entry and set them in a contentStream to write the upcoming text through contentStream.showText().

after 137 successful loops this error follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+00AD in font VVHOEY+FrutigerLT-BoldCn
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1CFont.encode(PDType1CFont.java:357)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:333)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:514)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:476)
at haupt.PageTest.printPdf(PageTest.java:294)
at haupt.MyTestPDF.main(MyTestPDF.java:54)
```

This is my code up to this step:

```
public void printPdf() throws IOException {
    TextPosition tpInfo = null;
    String pdfFileInText = null;
    int charIDindex = 0;
    int pageIndex = 0;
    
    try (PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(srcFile))) {
        if (!pdfDocument.isEncrypted()) {

            MyPdfTextStripper myStripper = new MyPdfTextStripper();
            var articlesByPage = myStripper.getCharactersByArticleByPage(pdfDocument);

            createDirectory();
            String newFileString = (srcErledigt + "Test.pdf");
            File input = new File(newFileString);
            input.createNewFile();
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            

            // For Pages
            for (Iterator<List<List<TextPosition>>> pageIterator = articlesByPage.iterator(); pageIterator.hasNext();) {
                List<List<TextPosition>> pageList = pageIterator.next();

                PDPage newPage = new PDPage();
                document.addPage(newPage);
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, newPage);
                contentStream.beginText();
                pageIndex++;

                // For Articles
                for (Iterator<List<TextPosition>> articleIterator = pageList.iterator(); articleIterator.hasNext();) {
                    List<TextPosition> articleList =  articleIterator.next();

                    // For Text                     
                    for (Iterator<TextPosition> tpIterator = articleList.iterator(); tpIterator.hasNext();) {
                        tpCharID = charIDindex;
                        tpInfo = tpIterator.next();
                        System.out.println(tpCharID + ". charID: " + tpInfo);

                        PDFont tpFont = tpInfo.getFont();
                        float tpFontSize = tpInfo.getFontSize();                            
                        pdfFileInText = tpInfo.toString();

                        contentStream.setFont(tpFont, tpFontSize);
                        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(50, 700);
                        contentStream.showText(pdfFileInText);

                        charIDindex++;
                    }                       
                }

                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close();
            }           
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("pdf Encrypted");
        }           
    }
}
```

MyPdfTextStripper:

```
public class MyPdfTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper {
   public MyPdfTextStripper() throws IOException {
       super();
       setSortByPosition(true);
   }

   @Override
   public List<List<TextPosition>> getCharactersByArticle() {
       return super.getCharactersByArticle();
   }

   // Add Pages to CharactersByArticle List
   public List<List<List<TextPosition>>> getCharactersByArticleByPage(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
            
    final int maxPageNr = doc.getNumberOfPages();
    List<List<List<TextPosition>>> byPageList = new ArrayList<>(maxPageNr);
    
    for (int pageNr = 1; pageNr <= maxPageNr; pageNr++) {
        setStartPage(pageNr);
        setEndPage(pageNr);
        
        getText(doc);
        byPageList.add(List.copyOf(getCharactersByArticle()));
    }
    return byPageList;
    
}
```

Additional Info:

- There are seven fonts in my document, all of which are set as subsets.
- I need to write the Text given with the corresponding Font given.
- All glyphs that should be written already exist in the original document, where I get my TextPositionList from.
- All fonts are subtype 1 or 0
- There is no AcroForm defined

Thanks in advance

## Edit 30.08.2022:

Fixed the Issue by manually replacing this particular Unicode with a placeholder for the String before trying to write it.

Now I ran into this open ToDo:
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType0.encode(int)

```
@Override
public byte[] encode(int unicode)
{
    // todo: we can use a known character collection CMap for a CIDFont
    //       and an Encoding for Type 1-equivalent
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Anyone got any suggestions or Workarounds for this?

## Edit 01.09.2022

I tried to replace occurrences of that Font with an alternative Font from the source file, but this opens another problem where a COSStream is "randomly" closed, which results in the new document not being able to save the File after writing my text with a contentStream.

Using standard Fonts like PDType1Font.HELVETICA instead works though..

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? Because multiple causes are possible. For example the **ToUnicode** map may map a single glyph code to a string of multiple characters. Or there may be discrepancies between **Encoding** information and **ToUnicode**. Or of course there may be an issue of PDFBox.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, unfortunately I am not allowed to share the PDF in question. I'll try your suggestions and be back once I can report on my efforts.

Comment: As mentioned, to properly analyze your original issue an example file would be needed for which the issue is reproducible. For the new problem you mention in your Edit 30.08.2022 the same holds. For the problem mentioned in your Edit 01.09.2022 additional details on your new code would also be needed.

Comment: That being said, the architecture of your approach is not optimal: You currently decode the encoded data from the source content stream to Unicode and then re-encode the Unicode data to the font encoding. A better approach would be to keep the original data in font encoding. Unfortunately PDFBox does not explicitly support this in its high-level API (there is no `PdfRawTextStripper` returning raw text data but still keeping track of the graphics state), but one can override and tweak the text stripper for that. And there is no `ShowRawText` but you can create the needed instructions manually.